# mysql.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, database, include

I have a simple c++ program. Its not even doing anything, just includes mysql.h.
I compile with this command: `g++ -o main main.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql`. The include path is correct, thats where mysql.h is. It says `no such file or directory` and i don't know why.